# TCP And Data Validity

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, network-protocols

I know what TCP implements in-order data transmission,but does it actually validates the data that arrived from A to B is the actual data that was sent from A ?
If it does , how exactly does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it actually validates the data that arrived from A to B is the actual data that was sent from A ?

Frankly, no.
It tries to make sure receiver gets the same number of bytes sender sent during session (using ack and syn numbers). It also makes sure every segment has correct checksum, which, I think doesn't guarantee much. If your host has faulty memory, it could be that you send one stream of bytes, then, a few buffers later some another stream of bytes (due to bit-flapping) is used to calculate checksum. The checksum will be correct, but the sent and received messages will differ. If you want reliability, always implement your own checksumming/hashing/signing of application-level messages.

Some relevant reading explaining a cost of a single bit error: http://status.aws.amazon.com/s3-20080720.html.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this excert from [RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) answers your question:

> ```
> The TCP must recover from data that is damaged, lost, duplicated, or
> delivered out of order by the internet communication system.  This
> is achieved by assigning a sequence number to each octet
> transmitted, and requiring a positive acknowledgment (ACK) from the
> receiving TCP.  If the ACK is not received within a timeout
> interval, the data is retransmitted.  At the receiver, the sequence
> numbers are used to correctly order segments that may be received
> out of order and to eliminate duplicates.  Damage is handled by
> adding a checksum to each segment transmitted, checking it at the
> receiver, and discarding damaged segments.
> ```